# How to show total number of quantity in invoice PDF using magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, pdf, customize

I want to show total number of quantity in invoice PDF 
even though I have managed to get quantity name on PDF

here is code for this

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Inchoo_Invoice>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Inchoo_Invoice>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order_pdf_invoice>Inchoo_Invoice_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
                <order_pdf_items_invoice_default>Inchoo_Invoice_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default</order_pdf_items_invoice_default>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
    <pdf>
        <totals>
            <qty translate="title">
                <title>Quantity</title>
                <source_field>qty</source_field>
                <font_size>7</font_size>
                <display_zero>1</display_zero>
                <sort_order>50</sort_order>
            </qty>
        </totals>
    </pdf>
</global>
```

**Invoice.php**

```
<?php


class Inchoo_Invoice_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
{
protected function insertImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $width, $height, &$page)
{
    if (!is_null($image)) {
        try{
            $width = (int) $width;
            $height = (int) $height;

            //Get product image and resize it
            $imagePath = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($image, 'image')
                ->keepAspectRatio(true)
                ->keepFrame(false)
                ->resize($width, $height)
                ->__toString();

            //$imageLocation = substr($imagePath,strlen(Mage::getBaseUrl()));
            $imageLocation = substr($imagePath,strlen(Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)));
            $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($imageLocation);
            //Draw image to PDF
            $page->drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public function getPdf($invoices = array())
{
    $width = 1000;
    $height = 1000;
    $this->_beforeGetPdf();
    $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

    $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
    $this->_setPdf($pdf);
    $style = new Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
        }
        $page = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $pdf->pages[] = $page;

        $order = $invoice->getOrder();

        /* Add image */
        $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());

        /* Add address */
        $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());

        /* Add head */
        $this->insertOrder($page, $order, Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID, $order->getStoreId()));

        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page);
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId(), 35, 780, 'UTF-8');

        /* Add table */
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);

        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y -15);
        $this->y -=10;

        /* Add table head */
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.4, 0.4, 0.4));
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Products'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        //Added for product image
        //$page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Image'), 245, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Stock Location'), 245, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'), 325, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Price'), 380, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'), 430, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax'), 480, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Subtotal'), 535, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

        $this->y -=15;

        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

        /* Add body */
        foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item){
                         if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($this->y < 15) {
                $page = $this->newPage(array('table_header' => true));
            }
                            /* Draw item */
            $page = $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);

            /* Draw product image */
                            /*
            $productId = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductId();
            $image = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
            $this->insertImage($image, 245, (int)($this->y + 15), 310, (int)($this->y+65), $width, $height, $page);
                            */
        }

        /* Add totals */
        $page = $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);

        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
        }
    }
    $this->_afterGetPdf();

    return $pdf;
}

public function newPage(array $settings = array())
{
    /* Add new table head */
    $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
    $this->y = 800;

    if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
        $this->_setFontRegular($page);
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y-15);
        $this->y -=10;

        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.4, 0.4, 0.4));
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        //Added for product image
        //$page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Image'), 245, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Stock Location'), 245, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'), 325, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Price'), 380, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'), 430, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax'), 480, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Subtotal'), 535, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->y -=20;
    }

    return $page;
}

}
```

**Default.php**

```
<?php

class Inchoo_Invoice_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default
{
/**
 * Draw item line
 **/
public function draw()
{
    $order  = $this->getOrder();
    $item   = $this->getItem();
    $pdf    = $this->getPdf();
    $page   = $this->getPage();
    $lines  = array();
    $stock_location = $this->getStockLocation($item);

    // draw Product name
    $lines[0] = array(array(
        'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($item->getName(), 60, true, true),
        'feed' => 35,
    ));

    //Inchoo - Added custom attribute
    //draw Stock Location
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($stock_location, 25),
        'feed'  => 245
    );
    // draw SKU
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($this->getSku($item), 25),
        'feed'  => 325
    );

    // draw QTY
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $item->getQty()*1,
        'feed'  => 435
    );

    // draw Price
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getPrice()),
        'feed'  => 395,
        'font'  => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right'
    );

    // draw Tax
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
        'feed'  => 495,
        'font'  => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right'
    );

    // draw Subtotal
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getRowTotal()),
        'feed'  => 565,
        'font'  => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right'
    );

    // custom options

    $options = $this->getItemOptions();
    if ($options) {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            // draw options label
            $lines[][] = array(
                'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split(strip_tags($option['label']), 70, true, true),
                'font' => 'italic',
                'feed' => 35
            );

            if ($option['value']) {
                $_printValue = isset($option['print_value']) ? $option['print_value'] : strip_tags($option['value']);
                $values = explode(', ', $_printValue);
                foreach ($values as $value) {
                    $lines[][] = array(
                        'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 50, true, true),
                        'feed' => 40
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Edited default line height
    $lineBlock = array(
        'lines'  => $lines,
        'height' => 40
    );

    $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, array($lineBlock), array('table_header' => true));
    $this->setPage($page);

}

private function getStockLocation($item)
{
        $prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

        if(!($return_location = $prod->getStockLocation()))
        {
            return 'N/A';
        }
        else
        {
            return $return_location;
        }
}
}
```

[image]

PDF is showing like that i don't know from where S$0.0 is coming from. How can I show total number of quantity please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add below code in your `.phtml` file.

And You have to find code in this `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\invoice` folder path for invoice.

```
$this->getOrder()->getData('total_qty_ordered');
```

You will get total numbers of quatity in invoice.

Comment: have you get solution ?

Comment: I think there is no phtml for this

Comment: Do you know the exact location ?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort @New Bee but i found my solution in other way

Comment: Can you please share your solution so that other can get better way to solve theire issue ?

Comment: Yes I post it. You can ask me if you have any query

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution myself here are the additional changes

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Inchoo_Invoice>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Inchoo_Invoice>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order_pdf_invoice>Inchoo_Invoice_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
                <order_pdf_items_invoice_default>Inchoo_Invoice_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default</order_pdf_items_invoice_default>
                 <order_pdf_totalpdf>Inchoo_Invoice_Model_Order_Pdf_Totalpdf</order_pdf_totalpdf>               
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
    <pdf>
        <totals>
            <qty translate="title">
                <title>Quantity</title>
                <source_field>qty</source_field>
                <font_size>7</font_size>
                <model>Inchoo_Invoice_Model_Order_Pdf_Totalpdf</model>
                <display_zero>1</display_zero>
                <sort_order>50</sort_order>
            </qty>
        </totals>
    </pdf>
</global>
```

**Totalpdf.php**

```
<?php
class Inchoo_Invoice_Model_Order_Pdf_Totalpdf extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default {

public function getTotalsForDisplay() {

  $order = $this->getOrder();
  $item = $this->getItem();
  $result = $order->getData('total_qty_ordered');

  if($this->getAmountPrefix()){
     $result= $this->getAmountPrefix().$result;
  }

  $fontSize = $this->getFontSize() ? $this->getFontSize() : 7;

  $totals = array(array(
            'label' => 'Quantity',
            'amount' => $result,
            'font_size' => $fontSize,
         )
     );

  return $totals;
}

}
```

thanx to @Wakanina https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497485/magento-module-add-rows-to-totals-in-pdf-invoice